# Custom Ldapauthenticationprovider spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security, ldap

We are working on a SaaS application which should capable of authenticating users against each client's LDAP server. So instead of hard-coding the ldap credentials in security xml, I should be able to dynamically obtain ldap credentials like url, dc etc from database and hit the ldap server with them. For this I need to customize Ldapautheticationprovider. Any tutorials, links, or guidance on how to customize Ldapauthenticationprovider will be appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could write CustomLdapauthenticationprovider and extend the original Ldapauthenticationprovider. 
In CustomLdapauthenticationprovider you can override the methods that you need to change.

In the xml, you need to change authentication provider to  your custom class:

```
  <beans:bean id="ldapAuthProvider" class="my.package.security.CustomLdapAuthenticationProvider">
```